# In the Blender 3D viewport (TOP VIEW) When I turn on the shadow option... how can I adjust the position of this shadow?

Tags: modeling, shadows, properties, custom-properties

In the Blender 3D viewport (TOP VIEW)
When I turn on the shadow option... how can I adjust the position of this shadow?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Workbench shadows are entirely fake, and independent of light direction.. there's a setting under the cog-wheel icon just to the right of your notation. Drag on the sphere:

[image]

Comment: wow thank you so much
May God's blessings be with Robin Betts who answered.

Comment: @SegyeCreative Let's hope God bestows ticks and upvotes, too :D